# How to calculate two complex variables integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, physics

The integral comes from the physics 
$$ I=\int^{+i\infty}_{-i\infty} dz_1 \int^{+i\infty}_{-i\infty} dz_2 \Gamma(-z_1)\Gamma(-z_2)\Gamma(-z_1-z_2)$$

I want to use residue theorem, since the Euler gamma function $\Gamma(-n)$ has simple pole at positive integre $n$. Here the trouble is that when I try to do the integral one by one, for example, when I integrate $z_1$ first, the $z_2$ is not a nonzero parameter always.

Comment: Is $\Gamma$ Euler's Gamma function? You should be more precise in your formulation.

Comment: @MrYouMath I think that is fairly obvious, isn't it? Especially after the edit mentioning the poles.

Comment: I don't understand why you try partial integration. Just do the $z_2$ integral first, noting that $\Gamma(-z_1)$ can be taken out. You should get a big sum from the residues. Then insert that in the out integral, which now is an infinite sum of integrals of a similar form. (I haven't tried it myself, so I suppose something could go wrong. But try it first, and report back.)

Comment: @MrYouMath,yes, it is Euler gamma function.

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen, when I do the $z_2$ integral, $z_1$ can be zero or can not be.If $z_1$ is not zero, it is ok. otherwise I do not know how to deal. Yes not by parts but one after the other, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Well, $\Gamma(-z_2)\Gamma(-z_1-z_2)$ has poles at $z_2=n$ and $z_2=n-z_1$ where $n$ is a nonnegative integer. The residue at each pole should be straightforward to compute.

Comment: how about special case $z_1=0$? since $z_1$ can be zero

Comment: I suppose you get a pole there. Ignore it at first, and come back to it later.

Comment: One more comment: Deform the path to avoid the origin, and all becomes much easier. This essentially adds or subtracts half the residue (times $2\pi i$) from the original integral, so is easily dealt with afterwards. I don't think you question deserves a downvote (after you edited it), so I am upvoting it to offset the downvote you did receive.